# What does XLLS mean?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there some relation between "XLLS" expression and AJAX / Javascript? What does the XLLS actually mean?

Thanks in advance

---

*adding text from a comment below an answer*

> ...the only result I got when I was looking for an answer on Google was the Excel XLLs but nothing related to JS. It's because I'm learning for an exam and there is a question to describe acronym "XLLS". Maybe typo?

Comment: Can you provide any context around where you saw/heard `XLLS`?

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of that in a Javascript context.

The only meaningful Google result I can see is [Developing Excel 2010 XLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687911.aspx)

Sure you don't mean [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)? or [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)?

Comment: It sounds pretty weird to me too. Like you already said, the only result I got when I was looking for an answer on Google was the Excel XLLs but nothing related to JS. It's because I'm learning for an exam and there is a question to describe acronym "XLLS". Maybe typo?

Comment: @starkjt - it is _your_ question. Where did you hear the term? In what context?

Comment: That's the problem. I didn't even hear it. The teacher gave us some kind of document where the frequently asked questions are (and those questions will probably appear on exam). That's why I'm asking. I've been looking for answer everywhere and didn't find anything with XLLS as referred to Javascript.

Comment: @starkjr I think it's most likely a typo.